# What is the difference in speed between the DLR languages and C# in Silverlight 2?

Tags: c#, silverlight, ironpython, silverlight-2.0, ironruby

For Silverlight 2, it looks like programming choices are:

- C#
- VB
- DLR scripting languages

  - IronRuby
  - IronPython
  - A sadly neglected (if not cancelled) Managed jScript

Is this a case where the native languages (C# and VB) are faster than the DLR languages by an order of magnitude or so?

Any hope of "living" in IronPython when I do Silverlight client programming, or should I expect to drop into C# for processor-intensive work?

My survey of languages comes from [this set of examples for C# and VB](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials.aspx) and [this page discussing the DLR](http://silverlight.net/learn/dynamiclanguages.aspx/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no hard and fast answer to this question. Performance of even the same language varies greatly based on a number of parameters.

Yes, in **general** VB.Net and C# will be faster than DLR based languages.  Static languages do more work at compile time such as method binding.  This type of work must be done at runtime for DLR based languages and hence they have a bit more cost at runtime.

However, lots of work goes into optimizing the DLR and DLR based languages.  Much of this work is mitigated by various caches and so forth.  In many types of applications, the performance difference will be negligable.

I would not rule out a DLR based language based solely on performance unless a profiler told me it was actually a problem.

Comment: All of that makes sense. I just wondered if people using IronPython are finding themselves writing more C# than they expected.

Answer (score 3):

Typically optimizing an algorithm will have a much greater effect than rewriting in a static language.

You might be interested in [Show #429](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=429) of .NET Rocks, an interview with Michael Foord. Here's a relevant excerpt from the [transcript](http://perseus.franklins.net/dotnetrocks_0429_michael_foord.pdf):

> Dynamic languages are a lot easier to
>   test, they 're really suited for the
>   Test Driven Development approach that
>   the developers were taking at that
>   time.  But I assumed that for 
>   performance reasons, they would have
>   to rewrite in C# at some point, and
>   then three and a bit years later we
>   got 40,000 lines of IronPython code,
>   we've got about 140.000 lines in a
>   test code, we've got some type  of
>   about 300 lines of C# and every time
>   they come to look at the performance,
>   every time they come and said locate
>   an operation that's not working fast
>   enough, we've been able to get the
>   speed we need by improving our
>   algorithms, by improving our Python
>   code and not having to drop into C#,
>   and the reasons programs run slow is
>   usually not the fault of the language,
>   it's the fault of the programmer, the
>   developer.

Comment: Hiding behind that beard is a lot of IronPython knowledge ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use Boo. Here is sample [Silverlight Tetris with boo](http://groups.google.com/group/boolang/browse_thread/thread/c25dd139c6ee3a0e/bf98ddc772d46004?lnk=gst&q=silverlight#bf98ddc772d46004)

Comment: The Silverlight CLR (2.0.5.0) is slightly different from the normal CLR (2.0.0.0), but in general yes most languages should compile for both by now.